# How to create a type level list with symbols to test a type family

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

I try to learn about Haskell type level programming. I wrote a little function to lookup a key, a Symbol, in a type level list:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

type family Lookup (x :: k) (l :: [(k,v)]) :: k where
    Lookup k  ('(k,a) ': ls) = a
    Lookup k  ('(x,a) ': ls) = Lookup k ls
    Lookup k '[]             = TypeError (Text "Key not found: ")
```

GHC (8.0.1) compiles this function without errors and 
now I need to test the function in GHCi. In GHCi I set the options:

```
:set -XDataKinds
:set -XTypeOperators
```

and try to run a first test example:

```
:kind! Lookup "bar" '[("foo", Int), ("bar", String)]
```

The Strings "bar" and "foo" should be Type-level Strings aka `Symbols`.

GHC rejects my little test case with:

```
<interactive>:1:14: error:
    • Expected kind ‘[(Symbol, v0)]’,
        but ‘'[("foo", Int), ("bar", String)]’ has kind ‘[*]’
    • In the second argument of ‘Lookup’, namely
        ‘'[("foo", Int), ("bar", String)]’
      In the type ‘Lookup "bar" '[("foo", Int), ("bar", String)]’
```

The question is how to change the test example, so GHC will accept it.

Note: My type level function `Lookup` is in its first version, it may be wrong, maybe I should use `CmpSymbol` or do other changes. However this is **not** the topic of this SO question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(k1, k2)` is the type of pairs of elements of type/kind `k1` and `k2`, and `'(a, b)` is a type-level pair (note the `'`).

```
'(a, b) :: (k1, k2)   with a :: k1 and b :: k2
```

Fix:

```
Lookup "bar" '[ '("foo", Int), '("bar", String)]
```

Comment: I just tried that: you need an additional space `'[ '(...`, otherwise the parser parses a character literal ... :) -- I felt free to edit accordingly.

Comment: Oh this i tricky: I assumed GHC would be clever enough to know, that in a type-level list '[] there cannot be value pairs but only type-level pairs...